# How to create a bootstrap element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap Element dynamically using Javascript. But the problem is that bootstrap class doesn't apply while creating the element.
Any Suggestions

**Here's the code that i tried!**

```
function show() {
var formGroup = document.createElement("div");
//formGroup.className = 'form-group';
formGroup.setAttribute('id', 'form1');
$('#form1').addClass('form-group');
document.body.appendChild(formGroup);

var label = document.createElement("label");
label.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
$('#label').addClass('control-label')
document.getElementById('form1').appendChild(label);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
var formGroup = document.createElement("div");
formGroup.setAttribute('id', 'form1');
formGroup.className += " form-group";
document.body.appendChild(formGroup);

var label = document.createElement("label");
label.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
label.className += " control-label";
document.getElementById('form1').appendChild(label);
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6h778etc/)

Comment: Tried this. Working now. Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `jQuery` in this line `$('#form1').addClass('form-group');` your `formGroup` element is not in the DOM yet, so `jQuery` can not find it. Try to add class by native method exactly to the newly created element:

```
formGroup.classList.add('form-group');
```

use the line above instead of `$('#form1').addClass('form-group');`

Comment: Working just fine now. Thanks.